# Can I use bag of words to find cosine similarity between vectors?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf

I have a Bag of Words dataset like this:

```
Item A B C D 
abc  1 0 0 1
pqr  0 0 1 1
xyz  0 1 0 0
```

and so on.
Is there a way I can find the pairwise cosine similarity in this dataset?
What I see on scikit is - converting it to a `tfidftransformer` version, and then finding cosine similarity.

The final aim is to compare the cosine similarity of my raw data vs the latent data (after modelling the data) and comparing the difference between the two.

Comment: can you explain little bit more about latent data?????

Comment: @qaiser okay so on giving raw data to a ML model (Variational Auto encoders) the data gets vectorized in the process. I need to actually find a way to download the latent vectorized data, and then find the cosine similarity between my raw data and latent data

Answer (score 0):

Some additional details can be added to the question to better present the question. For the given dataset, say the A, B, C, and D are the features, and you have 3 items 'abc', 'pqr', and 'xyz'. If you want to obtain a 3*3 matrix (len_items = 3) of pairwise similarity for each possible combination of items, then one of the simplest ways for the problem can be follows:

```
pairwise_similarity = np.identity(len_items)

for i in range(len_items):
    for j in range(i+1, len_items)):
        pairwise_similarity[i][j] = cosine_similarity(item_i, item_j)
        pairwise_similarity[j][i] = pairwise_similarity[i][j]
```

Finally, to implement the cosine similarity, you can write a function as

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c += a[i] * b[i]
    return c / float((sum(a**2)*(sum(b**2))**0.5
```

The above code can be further optimized by using existing libraries. For instance, for the cosine similarity, something like following can also be done

```
import numpy as np
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    cos_sim = np.dot(a, b)/(np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(b))
```

Alternatively, you can directly use `scipy and sklearn` to obtain the cosine similarity matrix directly. The could should be something like

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
pairwise_similarity = 1 - pairwise_distances(item_feature_matrix, metric = 'cosine')
```

Hope this helps.